# Regular expression to exclude tag groups or match only (.*) in between tags

Tags: regex

I am struggling with this regex for a while now.

I need to match the text which is in between the `<ns3:OutputData>` data`</ns3:OutputData>`.

- Note: after `ns`could be 1 or 2 digits
- Note: the data is in one line just as in the example
- Note: the `...` preceding and ending is just to mention there are more tags nested

**My regex so far**: `(ns\d\d?:OutputData>)\b(.*)(\/\1)`

Sample text:

```
...<ns3:OutputData>foo bar</ns3:OutputData>...
```

I have tried `(?:(ns\d\d?:OutputData>)\b)(.*)(?:(\/\1))` in an attempt to exclude group 1 and 3.

I wan't to exclude the tags which are matched, as in the images:

- [start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfPYe.png)
- [end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc0D1.png)

Any help is much appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

There might be some regex interpretation issue with Grep Console for IntelliJ which I intend to use the regex.
Here is is the latest image with the best match so far...

[image: latest]

Comment: Which regular expression flavour?

Comment: It's for the Grep Console in IntelliJ, I assume Java

Comment: Something like: `<ns\d{1,2}:OutputData>([^<]+)<\/ns\d{1,2}:OutputData>`?

Comment: may be something like :  <ns\d+:OutputData>(.*)<\/ns\d+:OutputData>

Comment: Please don't focus on how many nrs are after `ns`, we could easily assume `ns3` and work with that for now.

Comment: As in the linked question, either use a faster version with capturing groups, or use lookarounds (i.e. `(?<=(ns\d{0,1}:OutputData)>\b)(.*?)(?=<\/\1)`) If the engine is Java, you may use `{0,1}` quantifier in the lookbehind, BTW.

Comment: @tripleee I have looked at that answer, still doesn't match mine

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I have tried the expression, it doesn't seem to work, I am starting to doubt about the flavour. This might help: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125?pr=idea

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/iL0uY8/1

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Appreciate your answer, yet it still matches the tags as well; just like in the lower part highlighted in blue on your link. What I need is to match then exclude the tags so I would have only what remains in between `>xx<`

Comment: If you see [the source code](https://github.com/krasa/GrepConsole/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=regex), there are lots of references to Java regex. So, `(?<=(ns[0-9]{0,1}:OutputData)>)(.*?)(?=</\1)` must work. See [this Java demo](http://ideone.com/Xl7lgC)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew You are correct, it compiles and matches as in your example. It doesn't, in the Grep Console..

Comment: So, neither `(?s)(?<=(ns[0-9]{0,1}:OutputData)>)(.*?)(?=</\\1)` nor `(?s)(?<=(ns[0-9]{0,1}:OutputData)>)(.*?)(?=</\1)` nor `(?s)(?<=(ns[0-9]:OutputData)>)(.*?)(?=</\1)` work?

Comment: Hooray! @WiktorStribiżew the last one seemed to have worked (curious thought), I have made a slight modification of it

Comment: That means you cannot use any quantifiers in the lookbehind. Another test to make sure we get the right regex flavor: `(?s)(ns[0-9]+:OutputData)\K(.*?)(?=</\1)`

Comment: Nope, this one does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the answer in my case:

`(?<=(ns\d:OutputData)>)(.*?)(?=<\/\1)`

The answer is based on @WiktorStribiżew 3 given solutions (in comments).
The last one worked and I have made a slight modification of it.

Thanks all for the effort and especially @WiktorStribiżew!

---

**EDIT**

Ok, yes @Bohemian it does not match 2-digits, I forgot to update:

`(?<=(ns\d{0,2}:OutputData)>)(.*?)(?=<\/\1)`

Comment: But this doesn't match 2-digit ns (but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38658492/256196) does!)

Comment: You are correct, it doesn't match 2-digit; at the beginning in the comments I have specified that we could ignore the nrs of digits for now (then)

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is almost there. All you need to do is to make the inside-matcher non-greedy. I.e. instead of `(.*)` you can write `(.*?)`.

Another, xml-specific alternative is the negated character-class: `([^<]*)`.

So, this is the regex: `(ns\d\d?:OutputData>)\b(.*?)(\/\1)` You can experiment with it [here](https://regex101.com/r/tN5qV6/1).

**Update**

To make sure that the only group is the one that matches the text, then you have to make it work without backreferences: `(?:ns\d\d?:OutputData>)\b(.*?)<`

**Update 2**

It's possible to match only the required parts, using lookbehind. Check the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/tN5qV6/5).:

```
(?<=ns\d:OutputData>)\b([^<]*)|(?<=ns\d\d:OutputData>)\b([^<]*)
```

Explanation:

- The two alternatives are almost identical. The only difference is the number of digits. This is important because some flavors support only fixed-length lookbehinds.
- Checking alternative one, we put the starting tag into one lookbehind `(?<=...)` so it won't be included into the full match.
- Then we match every non- lt symbol greedily: `[^<]*`. This will stop atching at the first closing tag.

Comment: I have tried that, yet for some reason it still matches group 1 and 3. I'm starting to think there it might have something to do with the Grep Console interpreting the expression. But for other expressions work just fine. Please see the latest image.

Comment: As long as you're matching with a backreference `(\1)`, you'll have to match everything. But, depending this data being xml, you can make sure that the only group will contain the text only: `(?:ns\d\d?:OutputData>)\b(.*?)<`. If grouping is not enough for you, then you need [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). But, some flavors don't support that.

Comment: @TamasRev: Before posting an answer, pease read the requirement: *I wan't to exclude the tags*. If you read comments, you will see that the capture group solution is out of question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew we need to find a good balance between things like *answering the exact question*, *solving the problem* and *teaching good practices*. Anyway, thanks for pointing out this little detail.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you need a look behind and a look ahead with a back reference to match just the content, but variable length look behinds are not allowed. Fortunately, you have only 2 variations, so an alternation deals with that:

```
(?<=<(ns\d:OutputData>)).*?(?=<\/\1)|(?<=<(ns\d\d:OutputData>)).*?(?=<\/\2)
```

The entire match is the target content between the tags, which may contain anything (including left angle brackets etc).

Note also the *reluctant* quantifier `.*?`, so the match stops at the next matching end tag,  rather than greedy `.*` that would match all the way to the last matching end tag.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/B5r7o26wQX).

Comment: You are correct, this works as well; but I will stick to the most simplistic one